# What is the best approach for Navigating in Flutter when we depend on app state (example logged-in)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a Flutter architecture question on the best approach on how to navigate when we depend on the app state.

Let us assume we have a simple app that

1. shows `login page` if user is not logged in. On login the app does more things like track analytics, fetch extra data then needs to show the homepage
2. shows `home page` if the user is logged in

In order to know what to show initially, the app checks the secure storage for a previous token/session.

I will list below the two approaches I am aware of and the pros/cons I think they have.

**1 approach listening to bloc state**

The app can use a blocprovider and listen to the emited states.

Simple pseudocode example

```
 if (state instanceof LoggedIn) {
      return HomePage();
 }

 return LoginPage();
```

**Pros:**

Can be simple to understand

**Cons:**

If we need to prefetch more data after log-in somehow I see this approach needing to mix business login into the App.dart the presentation layer

**2 approach navigating from the bloc**

In this approach we can emit one event from the root app like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _appBloc.add(AppOpened());
    });
  }
```

Then on AppOpened event the bloc checks session if the user is already logged in, and based on this information redirects to login or home page using a navigatorKey `navigatorKey: _navigationBloc.navigatorKey,`

**pros:**

1. can do more extensive login in general like prefetch data, images etc. Even after the login-in, can make many api calls in parallel to fetch data, track analytics then when done just navigate to the desired page

**cons:**

The bloc pattern will be abused and the bloc will be also doing navigation not just receiving data and reducing a new state

**Question**

What do you think is the best approach ?
Please feel free to suggest other approaches as well. Those 2 are the only ones I am aware at the moment.

Comment: try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ray the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FutureBuilder like:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _appState.checkForLoginCredentials(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<bool>> snapshot) {
        return (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
            ? _getLauncherScreen(snapshot.data)
            : Container();
      },
    ))
```

which would call a method returning a boolean array like

```
    Future<List<bool>> checkForLoginCredentials() async {
    String? authToken = await getAuthToken();
    bool? onboarded = await isOnBoarded();
    ProfileResponse? profile = await getUserProfile();

    var isLoggedIn = authToken != null && authToken.isNotEmpty;
    var isProfileComplete = profile != null;

    return [
      onboarded ?? false,
      isLoggedIn,
      isProfileComplete
    ];
  }
```

You can use the values of the array of navigate to different parts of the application like:

```
//Returns the Starting Screen of Application based on the application journey
  //of the User.
  Widget _getLauncherScreen(List<bool>? data) {
    if (data == null) return Container();


    final isOnBoarded = data[0];
    final isLoggedIn = data[1];
    final isProfileComplete = data[2];

    if (!isOnBoarded && !kIsWeb) {
      return const OnBoardingScreen();
    } else if(!isLoggedIn){
      return const LoginBaseScreen();
    } else if(!isProfileComplete) {
      return const CreateProfileBaseScreen();
    } else {
      return const ParentBaseScreen();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to handle redirects in Flutter, but the one I use the most is with the `go_router` package along with `Provider` or any other state management solution you prefer, including listeners. The idea is to use the `redirect` function to manage all redirects, even if the user is logged in and you suspend their session; it will automatically return them to the login screen.

You can find more information about the `go_router` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router).

```dart
GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: notifierRouter,
    initialLocation: '/',
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: routeList,
    redirect: redirectRoute,
);
```

Here are some validations you could perform, just as an example:

```dart
String? redirectRoute(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    if (this.state.hasError) return null;

    if (state.fullPath == '/' && isLogged && isActive && !isExpiredSession) return '/home';

    if (state.fullPath == '/') return null;

    if (isLogged && isActive && isExpiredSession) return '/';

    if (!isLogged) return '/';

    return null;
}
```

Remember to adjust the routes and conditions according to the specific needs of your application. I hope this helps!